# Turn a svgator animated .svg into stepped animation...?

Tags: animation, svg, svg-animate

I am trying out svgator as an alternative to Lottie for a simple .svg animation. Works well and the output is more space-efficient than Lottie, however my very simple frame-by-frame animation shows a fade between states, what I am after is a stepped animation where each element is either 100% on or 0% off, nothing in between...

What I am trying to see is whether it is possible to easily convert (eventually my animation will be more complex) svgator output to stepped / calc:discrete type of animation...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 641 502" id="el_ilmpSLv-X"><style>@-webkit-keyframes kf_el_EjRrOdlIJo_an_Ti5zoWBvq{33.33%{opacity: 0;}36.67%{opacity: 1;}0%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 1;}}@keyframes kf_el_EjRrOdlIJo_an_Ti5zoWBvq{33.33%{opacity: 0;}36.67%{opacity: 1;}0%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 1;}}@-webkit-keyframes kf_el_pxtb1N0hIa_an_CNMulV32T{33.33%{opacity: 1;}36.67%{opacity: 0;}0%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 0;}}@keyframes kf_el_pxtb1N0hIa_an_CNMulV32T{33.33%{opacity: 1;}36.67%{opacity: 0;}0%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 0;}}#el_ilmpSLv-X *{-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;animation-duration: 1s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;animation-iteration-count: infinite;-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);}#el_nNxzkZk_8I{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_92gwHkp6Dw{-webkit-transform: translate(-290.19px, -43.13px) rotate(-13.4deg);transform: translate(-290.19px, -43.13px) rotate(-13.4deg);}#el_CxIlCYRcl-{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_nJSbOh9Iy4{-webkit-transform: translate(-289.5px, -45.31px) rotate(-13.19deg);transform: translate(-289.5px, -45.31px) rotate(-13.19deg);}#el_lbPqiFesmw{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_iffZT5dPse{-webkit-transform: translate(-289.65px, -45.25px) rotate(-13.19deg);transform: translate(-289.65px, -45.25px) rotate(-13.19deg);}#el_A_6l2_vhIk{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_OvlreNeNEJ{-webkit-transform: translate(-289.65px, -45.25px) rotate(-13.19deg);transform: translate(-289.65px, -45.25px) rotate(-13.19deg);}#el_I0gw6ENaS8{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_BLsas1YGgr{-webkit-transform: translate(-289.65px, -45.25px) rotate(-13.19deg);transform: translate(-289.65px, -45.25px) rotate(-13.19deg);}#el_gT1_0tq2B1W{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_oXzHc9EGd3-{-webkit-transform: translate(-289.65px, -45.25px) rotate(-13.19deg);transform: translate(-289.65px, -45.25px) rotate(-13.19deg);}#el_P-sV5PZm0YD{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_gNEMNxP5-y8{-webkit-transform: translate(-265.33px, -104.64px) rotate(-6.93deg);transform: translate(-265.33px, -104.64px) rotate(-6.93deg);}#el_AXxFNbxG9oQ{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_a-UZoypgSQP{-webkit-transform: translate(-268.97px, -89.09px) rotate(-7.88deg);transform: translate(-268.97px, -89.09px) rotate(-7.88deg);}#el_1aQzMExDvmj{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_gwdfyZ4YTB4{-webkit-transform: translate(-290.35px, -51.36px) rotate(-13.19deg);transform: translate(-290.35px, -51.36px) rotate(-13.19deg);}#el_7KW-yU3Eysy{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_NHylgBqgnWw{-webkit-transform: translate(-303.37px, -28.78px) rotate(-16.77deg);transform: translate(-303.37px, -28.78px) rotate(-16.77deg);}#el_bq1c8QFdu6R{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_KqudRjYIS5k{-webkit-transform: translate(-268.97px, -89.09px) rotate(-7.88deg);transform: translate(-268.97px, -89.09px) rotate(-7.88deg);}#el_lz0MOgbcZnB{-webkit-transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);transform: translate(-230.99px, -174.82px);}#el_Ge4Dsk3HHzq{-webkit-transform: translate(-268.97px, -89.09px) rotate(-7.88deg);transform: translate(-268.97px, -89.09px) rotate(-7.88deg);}#el_gLMxy-F6Bo{visibility: hidden;}#el_AnEa_QC8_j{visibility: hidden;}#el_2AvfH97ZDy{visibility: hidden;}#el_Esw-BxLaTXk{visibility: hidden;}#el_FFePyia9cPd{visibility: hidden;}#el_w33Wzt7EwmN{visibility: hidden;}#el_3VZE7jfwFnj{visibility: hidden;}#el_cPk2rY0Gan-{visibility: hidden;}#el_qtbY9iKcjwN{visibility: hidden;}#el_oeqpnshpnuh{visibility: hidden;}#el_pxtb1N0hIa{-webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;animation-fill-mode: backwards;opacity: 1;-webkit-animation-name: kf_el_pxtb1N0hIa_an_CNMulV32T;animation-name: kf_el_pxtb1N0hIa_an_CNMulV32T;-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);}#el_EjRrOdlIJo{-webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;animation-fill-mode: backwards;opacity: 0;-webkit-animation-name: kf_el_EjRrOdlIJo_an_Ti5zoWBvq;animation-name: kf_el_EjRrOdlIJo_an_Ti5zoWBvq;-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);}</style><title>blinkswivel_refix_Illout2</title><g id="el_pxtb1N0hIa"><path d="M720.74,472.13c33.89-5.12,61.38-25.58,79.29-49.87,16-22.39,25.57-55.63,25.57-94.63,0-45.4-10.87-78-33.89-101.66-30.05-32-81.84-51.15-161.12-51.15H231v501.9H401.7V499.62H557.06l124.68,177.1H872.27ZM531,384.43c-115.47,0-164.49-75.07-164.49-75.07s49-75.06,164.49-75.06,164.48,75.06,164.48,75.06S646.46,384.43,531,384.43Z" id="el_nNxzkZk_8I"/><circle cx="531" cy="317.87" r="48.83" id="el_92gwHkp6Dw"/></g><g id="el_EjRrOdlIJo"><path d="M720.74,472.13c33.89-5.12,61.38-25.58,79.29-49.87,16-22.39,25.57-55.63,25.57-94.63,0-45.4-10.87-78-33.89-101.66-30.05-32-81.84-51.15-161.12-51.15H231v501.9H401.7V499.62H557.06l124.68,177.1H872.27ZM531,384.43c-115.47,0-164.49-75.07-164.49-75.07s49.1-7.06,164.56-7.06,164.41,7.06,164.41,7.06S646.46,384.43,531,384.43Z" id="el_CxIlCYRcl-"/><circle cx="531" cy="317.87" r="48.83" id="el_nJSbOh9Iy4"/></g></svg>
```

I am aiming to see an animated 'r' where the drawn element is always solid black.

Comment: Can you build a [mcve] of the error you're facing and post it with line-breaks and indentation?

Comment: @Haem - - the 'error' can be seen here: https://private.modernactivity.com/ROGUEswiveleye_SVGATOR_01.svg

Comment: The letter shape should always look 100% solid, instead what you see is flickering due to opacity changes. 

If I put up the simplest possible animation showing a two-state animation we still see an opacity change. https://private.modernactivity.com/fixfade.svg

Comment: Original  svgator .svg code for keyframe values...

`@keyframes kf_el{33.33%{opacity: 0;}36.67%{opacity: 1;}}`

Comment: Looking at the .svg code, if I manually change the keyframe percentage values to be much closer like this:

`@keyframes kf_el {33.33%{opacity: 0;}33.34%{opacity: 1;}}`

Comment: the .svg is a lot less flickery, but actually what would be best if there was a way to output 'stepped' state changes, or what is called 'discrete' calcMode. I am unsure how I could apply discrete calcMode in this instance though! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/calcMode